# Outlook 2016 - Can I deliver from a non-IMAP account to an IMAP ost?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a local IMAP server and I'd like Outlook to use it as the store for email it receives though POP3. I've done this in the past delivering to an Exchange ost with no problems.

I thought I could do the same with the IMAP folders. However, the `Change Folder` dialogue for the POP3 account in the `Account Settings` window, won't show me any folders below the IMAP account name. I can even create a new folder from this dialogue, which appears in the folder list in the main Outlook window, but still isn't available in the delivery location dialogue. (`OK` is greyed out if I just select the IMAP root.)

[image: "New E-mail Delivery Location" dialogue]

I know there have been a few changes to IMAP in this and the previous version of Outlook, but although I've seen hints that this *should* be possible, I can't find anything definitive. (I know the reverse is not possible: IMAP mail cannot have its delivery location changed at all.)

Should this be possible or is this a known limitation?

**TL;DR:** Should I expect Outlook 2016 to allow me to deliver POP3 email into an IMAP account's set of folders?